problema con npm create vite@latest, no reconoce vite
estoy en un proyecto con vite, despues de instalar vite, ejecuto npm install, pero al correr npm run dev manda un error que dice "vite" no se reconoce como comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
Estoy usando windows 10, VS code, Node 20.17, vite 5.4.1
intente instalarlo global, no funciono.
intente instalarlo con pnpm tampoco funciono.
abri un proyeto de hace 1 mes, y ejecuto normal.
ccopie toda la carpeta node_modules del proyecto anterior y remplace la del nuevo, y si funciono, pero como estoy trabajando con tailwindcss, al ejecutar la instalacion vovio a fallar.
intente una instalacion por separado, y falla, segun yo, la falla esta al instalar node_modules.
Tambien hice el proceso en una lap con windows 11 y alli si funciono, observe que instalo una version mas nueva de vite, a diferenccia de la que se instala en mi lap con windows 10.
Que puedo hacer ?

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
